# How do I get a Bokeh ColorBar to show the min and max value?

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh, colorbar

I am making a bubble chart using Bokeh and want the ColorBar to show the min and max value.  Given data that looks like this

```py
In[23]: group_counts.head()

    cyl yr  counts  size
0   3   72  1       0.854701
1   3   73  1       0.854701
2   3   77  1       0.854701
3   3   80  1       0.854701
4   4   70  7       5.982906
```

I am generating a plot using

```py
x_col = 'cyl'
y_col = 'yr'
color_transformer = transform.linear_cmap('counts', Inferno256, 
                                          group_counts.counts.min(), 
                                          group_counts.counts.max())
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_transformer['transform'],
                     location=(0, 0))
source = ColumnDataSource(data=group_counts)
p = plotting.figure(x_range=np.sort(group_counts[x_col].unique()),
                    y_range=np.sort(group_counts[y_col].unique()),
                    plot_width=400, plot_height=300,
                    x_axis_label=x_col, y_axis_label=y_col)
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')
p.scatter(x=x_col, y=y_col, size='size', color=color_transformer,
          source=source)
plotting.show(p)
```

[image]

Notice that the min and max values on the colorbar are not labelled.  How do I force the colorbar to label these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the [`FixedTicker`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tickers.html#bokeh.models.tickers.FixedTicker) class, located under `bokeh.models`.  It is meant to be used to,

> Generate ticks at fixed, explicitly supplied locations.

To provide the min and max data values, specify the desired tick values then pass that object to `ColorBar` using the `ticker` keyword argument.

```py
mn = group_counts.counts.min()
mx = group_counts.counts.max()
n_ticks = 5  # how many ticks do you want?
ticks = np.linspace(mn, mx, n_ticks).round(1)  # round to desired precision 
color_ticks = FixedTicker(ticks=ticks)

color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_transformer['transform'],
                     location=(0, 0), 
                     ticker=color_ticks,  # <<< pass ticker object
                    )
```

[image]

If you want something a bit more exotic, there are 14 different tickers currently described in the [`bokeh.models.tickers` documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tickers.html) (do a word search for `Ticker(**` to quickly jump between the different options).